# html tags are not rendering in email message

Tags: java, html, xml, email, xslt

I'm getting email message with html tags from database and using that to create email content:

From database:

```
Service provided:<br/><br/> blah blah blah
```

These text attributes are stored in an object and finally they are transformed into html message by populating the values in an envelope. The part which holds the above attribute is like below:

```
Hello <xsl:value-of select="mail-root/contact/name/first"/><br/><br/>
Your account number: <xsl:value-of select="mail-root/account/account_number"/><br/><br/> 
<xsl:value-of select="mail-root/attributes/email_message"/><br/><br/>
```

The values are being populated properly and the html tags in the envelope are getting rendered correctly. But the html tags inside the email_message, doesn't render, it is shown as it is:

```
Hello test

Your account number : xxxxxxx

Service provided:<br/><br/> blah blah blah
```

How can i make it render as html tags? Note that I can also modify the content in database if the solution needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable-output-escaping="yes" helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

to your stylesheet?